# Invoking a Web Service using Curl Script

Tags: curl

How to invoke a Web Service using Curl Script but web service in turn should not return value. Curl Script should only invoke the Web Service?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Do you just want to access a web service URL and ignore what it returns?

Comment: yes...im using an asp.net web service..is it possible to invoke from curl?

Comment: Command line curl or one of the libraries? Should just be a matter of posting to the right URL. Maybe include more details about the URL, what parameters it needs, get/post/..., etc.

Comment: curl is great, but it doesn't invoke magic on your service any more than a browser does. It's all up to your web service if it decides to send data or not. If you simply want to ignore whatever is returned you can do that with `-o /dev/null` or `> /dev/null`. There's also the `-I` option if you only want to request the http-header.